# Is there a way of writing a FindElement call by passing in a string value for type

Tags: c#, selenium

I am currently writing a Selenium UI test for our new transactional website however whilst setting up the solution I am trying to find a more efficient way of creating a method to find my element without duplicate of code.

Ideally I want to create something akin to this:

```
    public void SearchForElement(IWebDriver driver, string elementType, string elementReference)
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementReference));
    }
```

Where 'Id' is the variable value 'elementType'

In previous solutions I have done the following:

```
            if (elementType == "Id")
            {
                returnElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementReference));
            }

            else if (elementType == "Name")
            {
                returnElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name(elementReference));
            }
            else if (elementType == "CssSelector")
            {
                returnElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(elementReference));
            }
            else if (elementType == "XPath")
            {
                returnElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(elementReference));
            }
            else if (elementType == "ClassName")
            {
                returnElement = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(elementReference));
            }
```

However as you can see the latter is in effect the same line of code that is only differentiated by the type.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to pass a string for the type?

Comment: As the UI tests are being written in parallel to the development of our transactional site (Not ideal I know) I find it easier to maintain an array of the elements that I am using however as there is little to no consistency on whether these have an associated Id I am finding that I have to use a variety of different types. An extract of the array I am using is:                 

{ "ppsBuyFlow","emailRegister","Id", "Email" },
            {"ppsBuyFlow","emailRegisterGo","XPath","/html/body/div[6]/div/form/div/div/div[2]/input" },

Comment: It might be better to create page models instead. You can define methods and properties without knowing the exact locators. Something like `private IWebElement EmailField => throw new NotImplementedException();` gives you enough to write some code.

Answer (score 0):

> As the UI tests are being written in parallel to the development of our transactional site (Not ideal I know) I find it easier to maintain an array of the elements that I am using

There is nothing wrong with writing automated tests in parallel to development. In fact, this is *the ideal way* to do it. You actually have a much bigger problem than the question you ask. Your problem can be addressed with a different architecture for your tests. Encapsulating automation behavior in a [Selenium Page Object Model](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/) allows you to partially create classes that other testers can use, but defer things like defining locators until you have a user interface to deal with.

As an example, imagine you are automating the UI for a todo list app. The UI isn't built yet, but that doesn't stop you from writing a test:

```
todoList = new TodoListPageModel(driver);

todoList.Add("Pay the electric bill");

CollectionAssert.Contains(todoList.GetItems().ToList(), "Pay the electric bill");
```

Your page model would look like:

```
public class TodoListPageModel
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    private IWebElement AddButton => throw new NotImplementedException();
    private IWebElement TodoTextField => throw new NotImplementedException();
    private IEnumerable<IWebElement> Items => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public TodoListPageModel(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void Add(string todo)
    {
        TodoTextField.SendKeys(todo);
        AddButton.Click();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetItems()
    {
        return Items.Select(item => item.Text.Trim());
    }
}
```

Properties that refer to elements or collections of elements can throw a NotImplementedException until you have a user interface. Then you can implement those properties using the correct locator, and run the tests.

Depending on who gets done first, you could inform the developer that the tests are written, and they just need to fill in the locators. After that the developer has tests to run during development, which is pretty nice.